# What is wrong with my SVG Path Code?

Tags: css, svg

I'm following this code pen but the author's code doesn't work for my own custom SVG from Illustrator. The original author puts a fill as an inline CSS style on the SVG path code. The white hover fill won't work if I don't make the SVG path code to white.

By default - The image is invisible but should be color #788F9B.

[image: Default]

On hover it works:

[image: hover rollover]

```css
a svg:hover #bino { 
  fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 209.84 136.85">
    <path id="bino" d="M58.07,139.42a23.28,23.28,0,0,1-23.13-18.92v2.63a22.71,22.71,0,0,0,23.13,21.55A22.34,22.34,0,0,0,81.2,123.15v-2.66A22.86,22.86,0,0,1,58.07,139.42Z" transform="translate(-10.14 -29.37)" style="fill:#29aae1" />
    <path d="M172.65,139.42a23.28,23.28,0,0,1-23.13-18.92v2.63a22.71,22.71,0,0,0,23.13,21.55,22.34,22.34,0,0,0,23.13-21.52v-2.66A23.28,23.28,0,0,1,172.65,139.42Z" transform="translate(-10.14 -29.37)" style="fill:#29aae1" />
    <path d="M204.72,82.65h0l-43.63-47.3a29.17,29.17,0,0,0-24.18-4.2,21,21,0,0,0-16.29,21v2.63a15.35,15.35,0,0,0-4.73-1.05,14,14,0,0,0-6.31,1.58l0.53-4.2a21,21,0,0,0-16.29-21,29.75,29.75,0,0,0-23.65,4.73L25.48,83.18h0a47.88,47.88,0,1,0,80.42,35.22v-5.26a11.25,11.25,0,0,0,8.94,4.2,11.93,11.93,0,0,0,9.46-4.73v5.78a47.83,47.83,0,0,0,95.66,0A46.83,46.83,0,0,0,204.72,82.65ZM58.07,151.51a33.11,33.11,0,1,1,33.11-33.11h0a33,33,0,0,1-32.8,33.11H58.07Zm114.58,0a33.11,33.11,0,1,1,33.11-33.11h0A33,33,0,0,1,173,151.51h-0.32Z" transform="translate(-10.14 -29.37)" style="fill:#fff" />
  </svg>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because the `style` attributes in HTML have precedence over the CSS stylesheet. Hence the color never changes.

You can solve this by defining the initial color in your stylesheet instead:

```
#bino { 
  fill: #29aae1;
}
a:hover #bino { 
  fill: #fff;
}
```

A working example:

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 166px;
  padding: 30px;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #166584;
}
.bino {
  fill: #29aae1;
}
#binocular {
  fill: #788F9B;
}
a:hover #binocular {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 209.84 136.85">
    <path class="bino" d="M58.07,139.42a23.28,23.28,0,0,1-23.13-18.92v2.63a22.71,22.71,0,0,0,23.13,21.55A22.34,22.34,0,0,0,81.2,123.15v-2.66A22.86,22.86,0,0,1,58.07,139.42Z" transform="translate(-10.14 -29.37)" />
    <path class="bino" d="M172.65,139.42a23.28,23.28,0,0,1-23.13-18.92v2.63a22.71,22.71,0,0,0,23.13,21.55,22.34,22.34,0,0,0,23.13-21.52v-2.66A23.28,23.28,0,0,1,172.65,139.42Z" transform="translate(-10.14 -29.37)" />
    <path id="binocular" d="M204.72,82.65h0l-43.63-47.3a29.17,29.17,0,0,0-24.18-4.2,21,21,0,0,0-16.29,21v2.63a15.35,15.35,0,0,0-4.73-1.05,14,14,0,0,0-6.31,1.58l0.53-4.2a21,21,0,0,0-16.29-21,29.75,29.75,0,0,0-23.65,4.73L25.48,83.18h0a47.88,47.88,0,1,0,80.42,35.22v-5.26a11.25,11.25,0,0,0,8.94,4.2,11.93,11.93,0,0,0,9.46-4.73v5.78a47.83,47.83,0,0,0,95.66,0A46.83,46.83,0,0,0,204.72,82.65ZM58.07,151.51a33.11,33.11,0,1,1,33.11-33.11h0a33,33,0,0,1-32.8,33.11H58.07Zm114.58,0a33.11,33.11,0,1,1,33.11-33.11h0A33,33,0,0,1,173,151.51h-0.32Z" transform="translate(-10.14 -29.37)" />
  </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: The default icon looks like this before the hover: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B04GcFLQkkBlNEVNTmphSzhlZlk/view?usp=sharing

By looking at this code, I was able to fix it to what I need it to be. Thank you.

Comment: @PandaNinja So, you're asking me to make it identical? :P

Comment: @PandaNinja Done it

Comment: No I accidentally posted. Then you responded to me before I could finish editing my comment. Thank you. This is closed.

Comment: @PandaNinja No fill I suppose, since you don't need the `style` attributes. I have no experience with Illustrator, however...

Comment: You're awesome!  For future reference, when creating an SVG in Illustrator what should the fill be to export the code properly to avoid this? Whenever I tried to use #788F9B as the fill in Adobe the hover wouldn't work. I always leave the stroke blank and clear. I outline the path stroke.